# Creating fulsome combinations of list elements

Tags: apex, list, recursion, algorithm

I have been having some issues getting the logic down for the following:

Simplifying, I have an N-element list of `Skids` defined as:

```
public class Skid {
    public Integer length { get; set; }
    public Integer width { get; set; }
    public Boolean turnable { get; set; }
}
```

I want to generate a List of lists of Skids, where each combination of a skid that is turnable (length / width get switched) is accounted for.

Ex.

Input `List<Skid>`:

```
[Skid(20,30,true), Skid(30,40,true), Skid(25,25, false)]
```

This input should be checked for skids that can be turned, and each combination of a turned skid creates a new list. I am looking for all possible ways to organize the list of skids.

Output  `List<List<Skid>>`:

```
[[Skid(20,30,true), Skid(30,40,true), Skid(25,25, false)],
    [Skid(30,20,true), Skid(30,40,true), Skid(25,25, false)],
    [Skid(30,20,true), Skid(40,30,true), Skid(25,25, false)],
    [Skid(20,30,true), Skid(40,30,true), Skid(25,25, false)]
    ]
```

I have been trying to get this to come together using recursion, but am having a hard time wrapping my head around it. How do I generate this output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want something like a Map<Boolean(turnable), List<Skid>>?  am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Looking for List<List<Skid>> as the result, where each inner list is a variant of the original.

Comment: What is the variant of the original?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to be specific about expected input/output and what it means to make that transformation. Also, please include an actual question. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the original question, hopefully it is more clear now. Sorry!

Comment: Confusing since `List<List<Skid>>` isn't valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to post an update with the answer to my question. Sorry if my explanation in the question was confusing, I will try to be more clear in future questions.

```
private static void generateCombinations_recurse(List<CommunitySkid[]> all_lists, List<CommunitySkid> accum, List<CommunitySkid> rest) {

     if(rest.isEmpty())
    {
        if(accum.size() > 0)
            all_lists.add(CommunitySkid.deepClone(accum));    

        return;
    }

    rest = CommunitySkid.deepClone(rest);

    CommunitySkid next = rest.remove(0);        
    //Now clone to get new Ids
    List<CommunitySkid> accum_1 = CommunitySkid.deepClone(accum);
    accum_1.add(next);
    generateCombinations_recurse(all_lists, accum_1, rest);        

    if(next.turnable && next.length != next.width) {
        CommunitySkid n2 = next.clone2();
        n2.turn();
        accum = CommunitySkid.deepClone(accum);
        accum.add(n2);
        generateCombinations_recurse(all_lists, accum, rest);
    }        
}
```